# Redeploy a web application using Wlst without starting it

Tags: python, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I'm using Wlst with a Python script to redeploy web applications. However, if the web application is not active, I don't want it to be started.

At the moment, I have to check the application state before redeployment and then stop it immediately after a redeploy. My current approach looks something like:

```
cd("domainRuntime:/AppRuntimeStateRuntime/AppRuntimeStateRuntime")
appState = cmo.getIntendedState("mywebapp")
deploy("mywebapp", "/tmp/mywebapp", upload = "true", retireGracefully = "true")

if appState != "STATE_ACTIVE" :
    print "stopping web application because of initial state: " + webappState
    stopApplication(appName = "mywebapp", retireGracefully = "false")
#end if
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to redeploy without the web application ever becoming active, so I don't have to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant, you may want to check out the `-distributeApplication` command. For reference, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1260412

Comment: When you provide a link to something, it's best to include enough information from the link for your answer to stay relevant even if the link breaks in the future.

Comment: I did look at distributeApplication. The main downside seems to be the need for a deployment plan XML which we weren't using at the time. In the end, stopping the web application after redeploy was deemed suitable enough.